# Create new image with transparent colour in jimp (js library) in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-manipulation

I am using jimp to manipulate the image. Everything is working fine but when I am creating a new image with

```
new Jimp(256, 256, (err, image) => {
  // this image is 256 x 256, every pixel is set to 0x00000000
});
```

> every pixel is set to 0x00000000

**I need no background color image (it need to be transparent),**
How can I achieve this?

**Edit**   : when I am sending a png image then it is giving me a transparent image,*when the third argument is not passed* when the third argument is not passed.
And jpeg is giving me black. 
And I am also manipulating image before sending or showing

Thanks for help.

Comment: Pass `0x000000ff` as third argument, that should set the alpha channel to FF, i.e. transparent.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this, as the last 2 digits of the color represent the alpha channel.

Or you can use a css color format:

```
new Jimp(256, 256, '#000000ff', (err, image) => {

});
```

As explained here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#creating-new-images

Comment: let me try it :)

Comment: which format are you using to save or display the image?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that jpeg does not support the alpha channel

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli thank you very much!!! Searched for a week I can't make a transparent image, turns out I saved it as `.jpeg` and not `.png` which supports alpha channel (transparency)

Answer (score -3):

Hex Color code for transparency is **0xFFFFFF00**